# failed to produce diagnostic for expression, Xcode 11.4, Moya

Tags: ios, swift, generics, option-type, xcode11.4

After updating to Xcode 11.4, I started to get this error

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression please file a bug report

On:

```swift
let provider = MoyaProvider<EndPoint>(requestClosure: requestClosure)
```

I updated Moya but it doesn't look like the issue. Runs fine on previous Xcode versions.

full code:

```swift
 let requestClosure: MoyaProvider.RequestClosure = {
            [unowned self] (endpoint: Endpoint, done: @escaping MoyaProvider.RequestResultClosure) in

       guard let request = try? endpoint.urlRequest() else { return }

       self.authenticator.authenticate(request, done: { (request) in
                done(.success(request))
       })
 }
 provider = MoyaProvider<EndPoint>(requestClosure: requestClosure
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, Xcode 11.4 compile issues are not verbose enough when it comes to `optionals` and `generics`.

Moya version and `Swift` version were not changed.

An issue with generics:

`let requestClosure: MoyaProvider<EndPoint>.RequestClosure`
Had to explicitly define the type in the closure, which makes sense, but was not a requirement pre-Xcode version 11.4

```swift
let requestClosure: MoyaProvider<EndPoint>.RequestClosure = {
            [unowned self] (endpoint: Endpoint, done: @escaping MoyaProvider.RequestResultClosure) in

       guard let request = try? endpoint.urlRequest() else { return }

       self.authenticator.authenticate(request, done: { (request) in
          done(.success(request))
      })
}
provider = MoyaProvider<EndPoint>(requestClosure: requestClosure
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the I was getting that error because one of my property was of type **Error** and I was assigning a value of type **LocalizedError** to it. Changing the property type to **LocalizedError** fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an Xcode bug for some cases at least. I renamed a protocol and then renamed it back and the issue was gone.